# Resharper 8 slows down the vs 2013 razor editor

Tags: razor, resharper, visual-studio-2013

I having problems with resharper in visual studio 2013 razor editor. Trying to move to another line of code with mouse gets about 1 sec to complete. Moving with arrows is a bit faster. Intelisense and code completion is very slow also. 
I'm using an Core i7, 12GB DDR3, RAID0 SSDs PC.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you running R# v8 or the new v8.1 update that came out a couple weeks ago?

Comment: I'm running the latest 8.1 version. Thanks for reply. I also noticed that suspending and resuming resharper fixes the problem. Also tried everything in http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Ultimate+Guide+to+Speeding+Up+ReSharper+(and+Visual+Studio)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Devexpress published an update to their vs menu integration (i think) which solves the problem.
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q561434
Thank you all.

Comment: DevExpress does not make ReSharper. Was it just a bad DX plugin *unrelated* to R#?

Comment: Too late to answer I think but if you follow the conversation in Dx support you will see it was related.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I manage to solve this by following the steps in [this blog](http://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/218-visual-studio--resharper-performance-tips/).

I didn't have to do all of the steps. The step that "saved" me was

> **Disable "Rich client visual experience"** in the "Options -
>   Environment". Here's how that settings page should look:[screenshot](http://d.pr/i/733e)

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution (Disable "Rich client visual experience" ) does not work for me.

I noticed that the problem only occurs when a document is reopened. If the document is already open when you open the Solution not the problem occurs.

Comment: Issue workaround: 
The problem can be rectified quickly by the Code window is completely split and the split window is the main window.

Comment: There ist a issue with DevExpress and Resharper http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-401187     https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q561434

Comment: Yes I posted this on dx support.